# Where can I find the link within admin for running the cleaner module, and how to install it?

Tags: 6, installation

I want to run 'Cleaner' (provided by the [Cleaner](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleaner) module).

But when I go to `administer > site > configuration`, nothing related to  Cleaner is listed.

I have searched Drupal.org, where I learned that this is this link is what I need. Maybe this information is out of date?

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I am new to Drupal. Can you tell me, how I install the [Cleaner](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleaner) module?

Comment: What information are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The [Cleaner](https://drupal.org/project/cleaner) module must be installed before you can use it.

Comment: Many thanks for quick response. I am new to drupal as a user and I am not happy with the company that built the site. Can you tell me, please, how I install cleaner.

Comment: Like anything, there is a learning curve. Drupal is a powerful and extensible system. As such configuring it for your particular needs can be a daunting process. You should review the getting started and after installation sections to start to understand how it works. In particular, [Installing contributed modules (Drupal 5 and 6)](https://drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-5-6). Good luck.